# None Output in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop

I am trying to loop a string using for loop, but instead, the "None" output popup.

how do I get rid of "none" output? thank you

```
def name(a):
    for b in a:
        print (b)

print (name("hello123"))
```

output:

```
h
e
l
l
o
1
2
3
None
```

Comment: The `None` isn't being printed by your `for` loop, it's being printed *after* the `for` loop has already finished.  Every `print` in the `for` is printing a string; the final `print` (in the last line of your code) is what prints `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `name` function doesn't return anything explicitly, so its return value is `None`, which you then print.

In this case, there's no point in printing the return value of `name` at all.

```
def name(a):
    for b in a:
        print(b)

name("hello123")
```

As an added note, this does not require a loop at all.

Instead we can expand `a` out to `print`, supplying newline as a separator.

```
>>> def name(a):
...     print(*a, sep='\n')
... 
>>> name("hello123")
h
e
l
l
o
1
2
3
>>>
```

This is equivalent to writing:

```
print('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '0', '1', '2', '3', sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the print command is used for each character within the *name()* function, there is no need to call it again with the final *print(name())* call.

In your code, the *name()* function prints each letter, and then the final *print(name())* function tries to print something as well. But since name() does not return any values, it prints "None"

This modified code should work perfecetly:

```
def name(a):
    for b in a:
        print (b)

name("hello123")
```

Incidentally, in this alternate version:

```
def name(a):
    for b in a:
        print (b)
    return "Done"

print(name("hello123"))
```

It **will** print another line, "Done", because the *name()* function returns a value when it finished, which is passed to the final *print()* function.

Answer (score -2):

Simple answer:

```
def name(a):
    for b in a:
        return(b)
print(name("hello123"))
```

Return function won't generate any "None" past the iteration.

Comment: Did you test your code? If you put a return statement inside a loop, it will only execute once.